# What is the fastest way to pre-populate an app with data?

Tags: ios, datastore

I'm creating an app that will have a lot of information pre-stored within it.

Would it be best to use a plist to store the data, or Core Data with SQLite? What is the fastest method to pre-populate the data in the app?

To give you an idea of the type of data I'm going to be using, you can think of storing movie information. I'm not actually going to be storing movies, but the data I am storing is probably similar in structure: One movie can have multiple actors, one actor can play in multiple movies.  Basically, there are many to many relationships in my data.

Comment: If there is relationship between entities, then it is best to use core data. A good tutorial for [importing data to core data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated)

Comment: I was also considering Parse to store the data which would give me access to update the data as needed.  My only concern is that it's going to be a free app and if it becomes popular I don't want to max out my Parse account.  Should I be concerned over this and is Parse a good alternative (seems to be to me). :-)

Comment: I'm not very sure which is the fastest way. I have always used Core Data along with [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)(A wrapper for Core Data), which provides some very simple importing of data from json/plist etc. If you app has static data you can probably use preloading. If you see there is going to be changes, make a data manager or something which checks for versions and update the preloaded data.

Comment: My question was re-worded to say something different than what was originally asked and then closed by other members as not being a good question.  What's up with this?

Comment: If you can justify it, I can vote to reopen it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able the start with a complete database, the fastest way would be to create a persistent store file that already has all the data in it and add it to your apps bundle. When the app launches for the first time, you could copy the the file from the bundle to the documents directory before setting up your `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and start using it:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]]) {
  NSURL *template = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSBundle pathForResource:@"start-database" ofType:@"sqlite" inDirectory:nil]];
  [fileManager copyItemAtURL: toURL:storeUrl error:nil];
}
```

After that continue as normal with the setup of your `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

You could pre-populate the database by running the app yourself, adding all the items, saving the context, and then quitting the app. After that copy the created sqlite database file and add to the resources of your app.